# copy/part with pair in REBOL 3

Tags: rebol, rebol3

`help copy` has the following to say about `copy`:

```
USAGE:
   COPY value /part length /deep /types kinds

DESCRIPTION:
   Copies a series, object, or other value.
   COPY is an action value.

ARGUMENTS:
   value -- At position (series! port! map! object! bitset! any-function!)

REFINEMENTS:
   /part -- Limits to a given length or position
       length (number! series! pair!)
   /deep -- Also copies series values within the block
   /types -- What datatypes to copy
       kinds (typeset! datatype!)
```

The `/part` refinement can take a `number!`, `series!` or `pair!`. I have not been able to get `pair!` to work. (I haven't tried `series!` yet.) Is this not implemented? If it is, how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **/part pair!** refinement works with images. The pair relates to the x/y coordinates as in

```
>> img: load %image.png 
== make image! [519x391 #{
1D2F9F1D2F9F1C2E9E1C2E9E1B2D9D1B2D9D1B2D9D1B2D9D1D2F9F1C2E9E
1A2C9C192B9B192B9B1A2C9C1B2D9D1C2E9E1D2EA01...
>> copy/part img 2x2
== make image! [2x2 #{
1D2F9F1D2F9F1D2F9F1D2F9F
}]
```

[REBOL/View Image Datatype](http://www.rebol.com/docs/image.html)

And here an example how **/part series!** is working

```
>> s: [a b c d e f g]
== [a b c d e f g]
>> ser: skip s 3
== [d e f g]
>> copy/part s ser
== [a b c]
```